# Check Dataframe for certain string and return the column headers of the columns that string is found in

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:
[image]

Now I simply want to return the headers of the columns that have the string "worked" to a list.

So that in this case the list only includes lst=["OBE"]

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'OBE': ['Worked', 'Worked', np.nan, 'Uploaded'],
                   'TDG': ['Uploaded']*4,
                   'TMA':[np.nan]*4, 'TMCZ': ['Uploaded']*4})
columns_with_worked = (df == 'Worked').any(axis=0)
columns_with_worked[columns_with_worked].index.tolist()

['OBE']
```

So the solutions construct a boolean Series of which columns contain the term "Worked". Then, we only get the portion of the series related to the true label, select the labels by invoking `index` and return that object as a list

Comment: How to check string as case insentive